# PrettyFaces does not work with Struts 2

Tags: java, url, struts2, struts, prettyfaces

I want to make my URLs nicer for SEO.

I configured the filter and it works with the following e.g.:

```
<url-mapping>
    <pattern value="/index" />
    <view-id value="/index.html" />
</url-mapping>
```

But when I set view-id to some Struts URL it does not work.

E.g.:

```
<url-mapping>
    <pattern value="/index" />
    <view-id value="/application/PunchIt.do" />
</url-mapping>
```

It can not find (or can not execute) Struts actions.

Is there any solution to configure PrettyFaces together with Struts 2 framework?

I'm using pretty-faces 3.3.3.

Here is the config of pretty-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/3.3.3" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/
               http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.3.xsd">

    <!-- doesn't work -->
    <url-mapping>
        <pattern value="/index.html" />
        <view-id value="/application/PunchIt.do" />
    </url-mapping>

    <!-- works -->
    <url-mapping>
        <pattern value="/error" />
        <view-id value="/error.html" />
    </url-mapping>
 </pretty-config>
```

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="struts_blank" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Struts Blank</display-name>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
      org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/* </url-pattern> 
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Show the complete configuration of a non-working example, e.g., the web.xml (or state you're using Servlet 3.0) with filter ordering intact, etc. It *should* work as-is... although I'm not sure why you'd need it since you can make nice URLs with Struts 2 directly.

Comment: I updated the post with configuration files..

Comment: If nothing else I'd put the PrettyFaces filter *before* the S2 filter so it has a chance to filter before S2 does.

Comment: No. It does not solve the problem. :-( I tried it already earlier. But I tried it also now. It is the same. It seems only one filter can be called. There is no, how to say, queue of filters. :-( If pretty-filter has been called, struts2 is ignored.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with either PrettyFaces itself, or your configuration of it--filters are filters, and chaining them is common and expected. Its docs state that if a URL isn't matched it will continue processing as normal, which is what I'd expect. I'd also consider mapping the S2 filter to the other request types, just in case. And again, I'm not sure why you don't just make the URLs nicer in S2 to begin with.

Comment: I wanted this url: http://www.example.com/appliction/strutsaction.do represent as http://www.example.com/index or http://www.example.com/index.html.

I want to drop out "/appliction/" from the url.

Comment: I fear your filters somehow concur(<load-on-startup/> is not set), please try adjusting (struts) url pattern to: `<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that the PrettyFilter is located before the Struts2 filter AND that the Struts2 Filter is configured to process FORWARD dispatcher types. So try something like this:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping> 
  <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
  <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
</filter-mapping>
```

For a detailed explanation, see question #2 here:

http://www.ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/FAQ.html